# Web application interface to module design

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, module, console-application

I'll start off with an overview.  I need to complete a process that is likely to take a long time to complete.  I would like to create a web interface that gets input parameters and sends these parameters to a separate module that completes the process.  The module would need to be able to call other web services.  I would like the web interface to be completely independent of the module.  That way, the user can leave the page, close the tab/browser, etc without disrupting the module/process.  Using a polling system, I could display to the user on the web the percentage complete.

My question is, what would be the best route for making this module, a web service, a console app, something else?

Both the web app and module would be in .NET.

Comment: Not sure if this is any use but take a look at http://signalr.net/

Comment: SignalR can only help with notification part of the story, but processing still has to be offloaded to another process if it takes significant amount of time

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a background worker process which can be easily implemented as a Windows service. Console application can technically work, but you have better control over service execution, security, restarting etc.

So your web app puts a request into a queue of some kind (e.g. MSMQ, i.e. `System.Messaging.Message` class, or some better implementation, or you can fake it with just database) and the service processes items from the queue at its own pace. Without knowing much about your requirements, I don't see a reason for going with web service as you will likely not expose it to the outside world.

Comment: Well, this process will probably be run once in a blue moon.  I guess I could have it run nightly and check the queue.  That wouldn't be much wasted.

Comment: I didn't even consider the performance in my answer, as I know too little about the issue. The service doesn't consume much resources by itself, so you can leave it running and it can periodically process the queue.